# ASP.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework can not insert record

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the following error when I try to add a `Schedule`.

> The column name 'Doctor_id' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.

Here is my schedule model

```
[Table("Schedule")]
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Booked { get; set; }

    public int Doctor_id { get; set; }
    //public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateSchedule(Schedule schedule)
{
    TimeSpan startTime = schedule.StartTime;
    TimeSpan endTime = schedule.EndTime;

    db.Schedules.Add(schedule);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the form

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Schedule</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <input type="hidden" name="Doctor_id" value="@Session["doctorid"]" />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a hidden input name `Doctor_id` with value for the create form.
Please help me with this, thanks.

Comment: You have not given us enough information, but [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059738/ef-and-tpt-the-column-name-is-specified-more-than-once-in-the-set-clause) might help.

Comment: Provide the view with the form please. The error is self explanatory.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak, I have provided the form

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code provided. Do you have some configuration for the model? What you `DbContext` looks like?